# Почему мягкий звук Л всегда обозначается мягким знаком?

Tags: орфография, мягкий-знак

Почему в правилах по орфографии особое внимание уделяется именно Л? К примеру, мягкий звук Р также всегда обозначается мягким знаком.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ ВОПРОСА.
Дело в том, что нет такого учебника по орфографии, где бы не говорилось об особом положении звука Л. Это выглядит примерно так: Ь в середине слова пишется: А) после мягкого Л, стоящего перед любым согласным (твердым или мягким: больной, сельдь, льстить,мальчик, пильщик ; Б) после мягкого согласного, стоящего пред твердым согласным: Кузьма, меньше, борьба; В) между двумя мягкими согласными только в том случае, если при изменении слова второй согласный становится твердым, а первый остается мягким: просьба - просьбе.
Это правило мне кажется совершенно бестолковым по следующим причинам: 1) оно никак не объясняется; Б) оно сложно в применении; в)далеко не все орфограммы можно решить с его помощью. Тем не менее оно уже много лет переписывается из учебника в учебник.

И вот мне интересно, почему по поводу мягкого Л мне задумываться не надо, а вот, к примеру,  слово "борьба" я должна проверять.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ К ВОПРОСУ
Уважаемые коллеги, прочтите, пожалуйста, мой вопрос в "Исследованиях" на эту тему. Почему-то его никто не смотрит.

Comment: Немного не ясно. Требуется уточнить вопрос и привести примеры.

Comment: Чего ж его проверять, если [р']произносится мягко? Здесь мягкий знак для обозначения мягкости согласного. Русский человек не ошибётся, а вот иностранцу приходится знать, что [л'] не подвергается ассимиляции по твёрдости. Правила пишут для всех пользующихся языком, не только для русских. Оставьте своё реформаторство, и так запутали всё.

Comment: В правилах для школы нет понятия ассимиляции, но есть правила, которые более чем несовершенны - по ним невозможно работать. Думаю, что русские люди правильно выбирают Ь именно потому, что не пользуются этими правилами, а пишут по интуиции. И именно эти правила рекомендуют мне и всем остальным (и русским, и нерусским) проверять слова "горький, возьми, усадьба,письмо". Слово "реформаторство", кажется, имеет отрицательный оттенок? А почему бы не переписать эти правила, чтобы по ним можно было элементарно просто решить эту орфограмму как младшему школьнику, так и студенту.

Answer (score 2):

Вы про сочетание согласных типа польза? 
Ассимиляция согласных по твердости осуществляется на стыке корня и суффикса, начинающегося твердым согласным: слесарь - слесарный, секретарь - секретарский и т.п. Перед губным [б] ассимиляция по твердости не происходит: [прΛс'ит'] - [проз'бъ], [мълΛт'ит'] - [мълΛд'ба] (просить - просьба, молотить - молотьба) и т.д. Ассимиляции не подвергается [л'], он остаётся мягким: [пол'ь] - [зΛпол'ныj] (поле, запольный).А мягкость, как известно, обозначается с помощью мягкого знака.

http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-023.htm